# Excel VBA - Move cell values up from application caller

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data table. When the user clicks 'delete' the applicable row is deleted. I want the data from the remaining rows underneath to move up one cell.

```
rs = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
```

I set rs as the row of the application caller (i.e. the rows that's being deleted) so I want every cell with a value higher that rs to move up one.

I guess it would take a while to cycle through every cell in the sheet? The table is set between columns B-P. At the moment the only column that has an entry in every row is B, so is there a way to work off that and to get the loop to stop once it hits a cell in column B without an entry?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in the delete command.

```
Range("Your Range”).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

That code is for a sheet row but you can adapt it to your table.

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
ws.ListObjects("Table3").Range.Rows(4).Delete xlShiftUp
```

That will delete the fourth row of the table. Yours would probably be

```
ws.ListObjects("Table3").Range.Rows(rs).Delete xlShiftUp
```

Here is some good info on working with tables. http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables

Comment: Worked a charm. Was trying to use .clearcontent. Thanks

Comment: Please click the little check mark under the up down arrows to let the community know that it has been answered.